# Bash: How to process all given arguments and store them into the array

Tags: bash, arguments

I'm beginner in bash  scripting and I'm having trouble with following script.

I want to process all given arguments from stdin. Then I check, if these arguments are ordinary text files. If yes, I want to store them into the array and later I want to go through the whole array.
But I am getting an error : word unexpexted
on the line with  *files+=("$@")*
I've tried to write it like this *files=("$@")*
but then I get following error on the line : "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")

I would be really grateful for any advice. Thank you in advance.

```
for file in "${argv[@]}"; do
    if [ -d "$file" ] 
    then
        echo "Error: '"$file"' is directory!" > /dev/stderr
    continue
    fi  


    if [[! -f "$file"] || [! -r "$file"]] 
    then
        echo "Error: '"$file"'!" > /dev/stderr
    continue
    fi  

    file "$file" | grep text >& /dev/null

    if [ ! $status ]
    then
    files+=("$@") 
    else
    echo "Error: '"$file"' not a text file!" > /dev/stderr
    fi
done

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
# .....
done
```

Comment: What is the $status variable? And don't you mean files+=("$file") ?

Comment: Why are you constantly UNquoting the part of your echo that MUST be quoted, ie. the $file?

Comment: status is never assigned; should be quoted in the [.  Make sure you're running this with bash, and not sh.  You don't read stdin anywhere and there's no indication of what argv is.  You should write to &2, not /dev/stderr.  To test a command, do `if command`, not `command; if [ ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
#!/bin/bash

files=( )

for file; do
    if ([[ -f "$file && -r "$file" ]] && file "$file" | grep -q -i "text"); then
        files+=( "$file" )
    fi
done

for f in ${files[@]}; do
    # something with "$f"
done
```

Another version, with error handling :

```
#!/bin/bash

files=( )

for file; do
    if [[ ! -f "$file ]]; then
        echo >&2 "$file is not a regular file"
        continue
    fi

    if [[ ! -r "$file ]]; then
        echo >&2 "$file is not readable for $USER"
        continue
    fi

    if ! file "$file" | grep -q -i "text"; then
        echo >&2 "$file is not a text file"
        continue
    fi

    files+=( "$file" )
done

for f in ${files[@]}; do
    # something with "$f"
done
```

**NOTE**

- `argv` doesn't exists literally in `bash`,  `for file` is sufficient
- instead of using non existent variable `$status`, use predefined variable `$?`
- no need to test last status, you can do something shorter like `grep -q pattern file && do_something`
- `echo >&2` mean to redirect to `STDERR`

Comment: I tried your versions, but  at the line with  files=( ) I get an error : "(" unexpected

Comment: I tried to write it like: declare -a file   or  declare -a file='()' (I found it in some tutorial)but then I get error: word unexpected (expecting ")") or : declare not found

Comment: Seems youre using the wrong shell. Try this : `chmod +x script.sh; ./script.sh` with the new version (added a shebang)

Comment: or more portably change the first line to `#! /usr/bin/env bash` (allows `bash` to be anywhere on your `$PATH`), alternatively try explicitly with `bash script.sh` to see if it runs then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I just coded and seems to do what you ask...
Just replace the .. in the third test with whatever you need.
Unfortunately, I have never used arrays in the manner you do above,
so I just wrote it my way. I hope it helps. Just run it as bash {scriptname}.sh. Anything entered into standard in will process.

```
#!/bin/bash

checkfile()
{

for i in $token
    do  

        if [ -f "${i}" ]; then
            {
            echo "It's a file"
            }   
        elif [ -d "${i}" ]; then
            {
            echo "It's a directory"
            }       
        elif [ -z "${i}" ]; then
            {
                :
            }
        fi

    done


}

while ( : )
do
    read token
    checkfile
    sleep 2
done
```

Here is the debug output in bash:

```
+ read token
a
+ checkfile
+ for i in '$token'
+ '[' -f a ']'
+ '[' -d a ']'
+ echo 'It'\''s a directory'
It's a directory
+ sleep 2
+ :
+ read token
b
+ checkfile
+ for i in '$token'
+ '[' -f b ']'
+ echo 'It'\''s a file'
It's a file
+ sleep 2
+ :
+ read token
a
+ checkfile
+ for i in '$token'
+ '[' -f a ']'
+ '[' -d a ']'
+ echo 'It'\''s a directory'
It's a directory
+ sleep 2
+ :
+ read token
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sputnick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415158/1933494) is a very good solution. Just in case you want to stick with your own implementation, make sure you correct the following line:

```
if [[! -f "$file"] || [! -r "$file"]]
```

You should always leave spaces between the brackets and the test expression: `[[ ! -f "$file" ]]`. Also, since you are using the `||` operator, use double brackets rather than single ones:

```
if [[ ! -f "$file" ]] || [[ ! -r "$file" ]]
```

Change the line `files+=("$@")` to either `files+=( "$file" )` or `files[${#files[@]}]="$file"`.

Not sure what you wanted to do with your `status` variable. The test `[ ! $status ]` will return True for an unassigned `status`, a variable assigned like `status=` or any `status=$(command >& /dev/null)`. If you want to test against the exit status of the `file ...` command, use integer tests rather than string comparison: `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` or `if (($? == 0))`.